# MS project - tentative task date and followup

Tags: ms-project

New to MS project. Maybe I am not using it entirely to manage project, but resources. I wanted to plan installation dates of our technician. I know the tentative/estimated date. I can enter a task in MSP 2010, but how to differentiate it from confirmed dates.

For example, I wanted to see it in a report that for that task the date is not confirmed yet, and need follow-up.

Answer (score 1):

For those tasks, milestones, or external inputs where the date is still unknown, leave those line unbaselined.  If the rest of your project is baselined, then the dates for the unknown lines will be blank.

EDIT: A baseline is more than a snapshot.  It serves as your commitment and an input for measurement using things like EV.

Once baselined, I do not think you can reverse it.  You can purposely baseline a select portion of your project, leaving control accounts and work packages unbaselined, which is essentially progressive elaboration, which is what you want.  When your dates become more certain, you can strike a baseline for those accounts or packages or milestones and begin working towards them.

MSProject allows for multiple baselines, as well.  Or, you can rebaseline if a date changed and was approved through your change control processes.

The whole point behind a baseline is that it does not arbitrarily change.  Once set, it is set and you measure from there.

Is this helping?

Comment: I am yet to set a baseline for the project, but as far as i see, it is a snapshot. can u please show me a link to how can i unbaseline a  task. I searched, could not locate anything. May be a different terminology. thanks for your help.